# Pure CSS scroll shadows

Tags: html, css

I want to enable scroll shadows when content exceeds the available width. This I am trying to achieve with pure CSS (no JS). Using a technique I found in various articles, I can achieve my goal with multiple CSS backgrounds and `background-attachment`.

The below code is working fine if the content is text only. However, in the case of buttons, the shadow backgrounds get displayed *behind* the buttons. How can I display these shadows *above* the buttons?

**Expected behavior:**

[image: three shadow scenarios]

Scenario A: enable shadow only at right side, as scroll bar is at extreme left

Scenario B: enable shadows on both right & left side, as scroll bar is somewhere in the middle

Scenario C: enable shadow only at left side, as scroll bar is at extreme right

**Example:**

```css
/**
 * Scrolling shadows by @kizmarh and @leaverou
 * Only works in browsers supporting background-attachment: local; & CSS gradients
 * Degrades gracefully
 */

html {
  background: white;
  font: 120% sans-serif;
}
.scrollbox {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:
  /* Shadow covers */
  linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 70%) 0 100%,
  /* Shadows */
  radial-gradient(50% 0, farthest-side, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(50% 100%, farthest-side, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
  background:
  /* Shadow covers */
  linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 70%) 0 100%,
  /* Shadows */
  radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: 100% 40px, 100% 40px, 100% 14px, 100% 14px;
  /* Opera doesn't support this in the shorthand */
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Ah! Scroll below!</li>
    <li><button>Button</button></li>
    <li><button>Button</button></li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li><button>Button</button></li>
    <li><button>Button</button></li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>The end!</li>
    <li>No shadow there.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, see this implementation: https://codepen.io/matthewbeta/pen/fzoHI

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, somewhat inspired by the other answers, here is a horizontally scrolling scrollbox as OP asked for.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.scrollbox {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

.item {
  height: 30vh;
  aspect-ratio: 1.41;
  background-color: silver;
}

.shadowHider {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}
.shadowHider--end {
  position: sticky;
  margin-left: -2rem;
  flex: 0 0 1rem;
  left: calc(100% - 1rem);
}

.shadow {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 30vh;
  flex: 0 0 1rem;
}

.shadow--start {
  left: 0;
  margin-right: -1.5rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0004, transparent);
}

.shadow--end {
  right: 0;
  margin-left: -1.5rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #0004);
  height: 30vh;
  width: 1rem;
  left: calc(100% - 2rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbox">
  <div class="shadowHider shadowHider--start"></div>
  <div class="shadow shadow--start"></div>
  
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  
  <div class="shadow shadow--end"></div>
  <div class="shadowHider shadowHider--end"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens for the text as well, but you can't see it because they are of the same color. A solution would be to use a lower `z-index` for the children than for the parent. For this to work, you need two other things:

1. A `position` other than `static` for the children and the parent
2. A transparent background for `.scrollbox`

### Solution

```css
.scrollbox li * {
  z-index:0;
  position:relative;
}
.scrollbox {
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

```css
/**
 * Scrolling shadows by @kizmarh and @leaverou
 * Only works in browsers supporting background-attachment: local; & CSS gradients
 * Degrades gracefully
 */

html {
  background: white;
  font: 120% sans-serif;
}
.scrollbox {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 160px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background:
  /* Shadow covers */
  linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 70%) 0 100%,
  /* Shadows */
  radial-gradient(50% 0, farthest-side, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(50% 100%, farthest-side, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
  background:
  /* Shadow covers */
  linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 70%) 0 100%,
  /* Shadows */
  radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 100% 40px, 100% 40px, 100% 14px, 100% 14px;
  /* Opera doesn't support this in the shorthand */
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
}

.scrollbox li * {
  z-index:0;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Ah! Scroll below!</li>
    <li><button>Button</button></li>
    <li><button>Button</button></li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li><button>Button</button></li>
    <li><button>Button</button></li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>The end!</li>
    <li>No shadow there.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The only problem left is that you need a solid background color for this to work.

### Edit:

The `z-index` of the children needs to be lower than the one of the parent, but if you use a negative `z-index`, like I suggested, events like click and hover stop working. I changed the code appropriately.

Comment: Lea Verou's solution doesn't work anymore at chrome. Roman Komarov's solution still works http://kizu.ru/en/fun/shadowscroll/

Comment: Are you sure this works.. I tried this and also the example in the code snippet here shows the buttons on top of the shadow..

Comment: This did not work.

Answer (score 0):

this work for every content and scroll shadow always will be on top.

i use tags to be easy for understand. we also can use pseudo elements.

```css
       
    :root{
        --scroll-height : 160px
    }

    html {
        background: white;
        font: 120% sans-serif;
    }

    .parent {
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 200px;
        max-height: var(--scroll-height );
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }



    .top-hider {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: white;
        height: 10px;
        width: 200px;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .bottom-shadow {
        position: sticky;
        top: calc(var(--scroll-height ) - 23px);
        left: 0;
        background: radial-gradient(#c8c8c8, #ffffff94 77%);
        height: 10px;
        width: 200px;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    .top-shadow {
        position: sticky;
        top: -2px;
        left: 0;
        background: radial-gradient(#c8c8c8, #ffffff94 77%);
        height: 10px;
        width: 200px;
        z-index: 4;
    }

    .bottom-hider {
        background: white;
        height: 10px;
        width: 200px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="top-shadow"></div>
    <div class="top-hider"></div>
    <div class="bottom-shadow"></div>
    <ul class="container">
        <li>Ah! Scroll below!</li>
        <li>
            <button>Button</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button>Button</button>
        </li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>
            <button>Button</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button>Button</button>
        </li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>The end!</li>
        <li>No shadow there.</li>

    </ul>
    <div class="bottom-hider"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
.scrollGradient {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#f429b7 33%, rgba(244,41,183,0)),
    linear-gradient(rgba(244,41,183, 0), #f429b7 66%) 0 100%,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(34,34,34, 0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(34,34,34,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%;
  background-color: #f429b7;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
  background-size: 100% 45px, 100% 45px, 100% 15px, 100% 15px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).